# Path to inherit ancestor foreground brush color

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, triggers, binding

I'm currently in progress of writing an extension for the `Path` object. What I want it to do is to inherit it's (first) `Control` ancestor `Foreground` color.

This is what I have so far...

```
public override void OnValueChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is Path path)
    {
        path.Loaded -= Path_Loaded;
        path.Loaded += Path_Loaded;
    }
}

private void Path_Loaded(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (!(sender is Path path))
    {
        return;
    }

    // Find first ancestor
    var parent = path.Parents().OfType<Control>().FirstOrDefault();

    if (parent != null)
    {
        // Apply the template
        parent.ApplyTemplate();

        // Set parent's control foreground
        path.Fill = parent.Foreground;
    }
    else
    {
        // Fallback to default
        path.Fill = Brushes.Black;
    }
}
```

It works fine for a simple control, however it's disadvantage is that, once the `Fill` is set, it leaves forever. I would like it also to inherit the foreground when the ancestor's foreground *changes* due to a trigger (eg. the mouse over, or whatever binding).

**What have I tried**: Checking the ancestor for any triggers, then hook into the mouse over event... but I find it a weak, one dimensional solution as it wont affect other triggers.

**How can I manage apply a "live" color of the ancestor control, as it changes?**

## edit

This simple binding does just what I want, however it is proceeding the warnings in console if no ancestor was located:

```
<Path Fill="{Binding Foreground, FallbackValue=Black, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Control}}"/>
```

Comment: You can ignore this binding warning or error as they are handled by WPF internally. The XAML parser tries to resolve the binding, the very moment the `Path` instance is created. Since it is not part of visual tree at the moment of instantiation, the binding fails at first, but as soon as added to the tree and a matching ancestor could be found the binding resolves. If no matching ancestor exists, the parser tries to apply a fallback value. If no such value was defined the binding is 'officially' unresolved. All errors between this last state back to instantiation are already handled internally

Comment: @BionicCode I might ignore them, but there is just too much of them, because there are several vectors appearing in the list. If I turn off warnings in Visual Studio, it will affect other, potentially important ones.

Comment: Where is `Path` defined, in a `ResourceDictionary` or a `MergedDictionary`? Try to move the `Path` out of any `MergedDictionary` and into the App.xaml. This should turn the error or warnings into info. But keep in mind that the errors you see in the output window are just logging results. The actual exception was already handled (otherwise the application would've crashed). And since you're only getting _warnings_ you might consider to change the output level to error (if you can't ignore those binding warnings)

Comment: Or if `Path` is used within a style, then move it to this style's `Style.Resources`